# How should I use the Java 8 date classes with io.jsonwebtoken?

Tags: java, java-8, jwt

I have a Spring Boot JSON Api and for authentication I'm using JWT tokens. To generate JWT toke I'm using **io.jsonwebtoken** library. The whole application uses **java.time.ZonedDateTime** for **Date** fields, however the **io.jsonwebtoken** relies on the old **java.util.Date** which creates is creating a lot of issues. Any suggestion on what can be the easiest way to make them compatible, provided I keep wanting to use the new **Date** classes provided by Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far i know `io.jsonwebtoken` does not support for new `java.time` classes, you can convert `java.time.ZonedDateTime` to `java.util.Date` and use them in date fields.

```
Date.from(java.time.ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant());
```

Comment: So will that be precise? Essentially I need to perform some comparison between datetime, So my domain object  field is created by using ZonedDateTime.now() and the JWT token creation date will be like Date.from(java.time.ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant());, so will that be effective form comparisons between two?

Comment: @Paras in your jwt creation logic, just convert it to Date, .setIssuedAt(Date.from(zoneddatetime.toInstant())), it wont be a problematic